# binding an asp.net checkbox on serverside

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, binding, datalist

I have an search functionality in which the checkbox should come as checked or unchecked based on the data these check boxes were multiple and I am doing it on server side here I have is  the code

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="AApBlue" runat="server"Checked='<%#GetBoolean(Eval("blueFlag").ToString()) %>'/>Blue

.cs file 
protected Boolean GetBoolean(string val)
{
    return val == "Y" ? true : false;
}
```

I am getting an error:

> object reference null pointer exception

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Method 1:

You should try ItemDataBound event, add a Label and set it as visible false:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="AApBlue" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<% # Eval("blueFlag") %>' Visible="false" runat="server" >
</asp:Label>

.CS File:
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        CheckBox chk = e.Item.FindControl("AApBlue") as CheckBox;
        Label lbl = e.Item.FindControl("Label1") as Label;

        chk.Checked = (lbl.Text == "Y") ? true : false;
    }
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add `OnItemDataBound` event in DataList.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
```

---

### Method 2:

You can use ternary operator in checkbox checked as:

```
Checked='<% # (Eval("blueFlag").ToString() == "Y") ? true : false %>'
```